# "net::ERR_CACHE_MISS" when loading an external URL in Cordova

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova

I am getting crazy about this. I have a pretty basic Cordova (3.5.0) app and want to load an external URL. The only thing I am doing is loading jQuery (locally) and executing this on button click:

```
$.ajax({
  dataType:'html',
  url:'http://www.google.com',
  success:function(data) {
    $('#ajax').html($(data).children());   
  }
});
```

Everytime on loading my app fires this error:

```
GET http://www.google.com/ net::ERR_CACHE_MISS    jquery.min.js:4
send                                              jquery.min.js:4
m.extend.ajax                                     jquery.min.js:4
(anonymous function)                              index.html:68
m.event.dispatch                                  jquery.min.js:3
r.handle                                          jquery.min.js:3
```

All permissions are properly set in the AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permissions.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permissions.NETWORK_ACCESS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permissions.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Does anyone of you had a similar issue? What does net::ERR_CACHE_MISS means?

Comment: What if you add `cache: false` to your ajax call, to make it not look for the cached response? This typically occurs when you navigate back to a form that cannot be cached.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately it did not resolve this. Still getting the same error.

Comment: I do not know what kind of external URL you're mentioning (assuming you're only testing www.google.com) but maybe an `$.ajax` call is not suitable here, since it needs previous data to properly load the current document (basically what **ERR_CACHE_MISS** means) you could just do this instead? [**JsFiddle Link**](http://jsfiddle.net/urbz/tuovhtcw/)

Comment: google.com is just for testing purpose. When I managed to solve this I want to load a JSONP resource. Anyway I tried your code to verify that I can load any external ressource but it resulted in an alert with "net::ERR_CACHE_MISS (http://www.aftonbladet.se/)" again :(

Comment: Oh damn... sometimes you just need to step back... 
Beginner's mistake: it is 

    **android.permission.** 

and not 
    android.permissions. 
Resolved!

Comment: Classical! Think easy. Not always that easy though.. ;-) Nice too see you resolved it!

Comment: Yeah, that's true. Thanks anyway for your effort.

Comment: You should write an answer and mark it as solved ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Oh damn... sometimes you just need to step back... Beginner's mistake: it is android.permission. and not android.permissions. Resolved!

Answer (score 8):

All i had to do was:

```
cordova platform remove android
cordova platform add android
```

and the "net::ERR_CACHE_MISS" error disappeared. I have no idea what the reason was.

Comment: This solution worked for me.  In my case, the initial problem was caused by removing a cordova plugin.

Comment: omg, this is the most infuriating kind of shit to deal with when developing. THANKS!!!!!

Answer (score 4):

The used syntax is wrong.

Your used:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permissions.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permissions.NETWORK_ACCESS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permissions.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Correct:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NETWORK_ACCESS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Name "android.permission" is singular.

Comment: You also need to make sure the `android` namespace is declared in the `config.xml` file: `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"`

Answer (score 2):

**net::ERR_CACHE_MISS** is not a bad error, it simply means the page loaded has not been cached, if you go to a cached page the error should not show up. Most pages now will show this error, and while annoying it shouldn't do any damage to your application.

Answer (score 2):

solved by adding internet permission in manifesto file

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

Comment: I think you meant Android manifest, but you were absolutely correct in my case.

Answer (score -1):

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CACHE_MISS

This can be removed by simply running these commands

1. `ionic cordova platform rm android --save`
2. `ionic cordova platform add android --save`